# Error messages getting lost when using redirect Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC based application and need to show the error message to the end 
user in case something goes wrong in the process.here is the piece of code i am doing

```
GlobalMessages.addErrorMessage(model, "facebook.user.accessDenied");
return REDIRECT_PREFIX + "http://localhost:8080/storefront";
```

i am using tags in the UI to show the error message,but seems like using redirect just dropping my error message.
I am new to Spring-MVC and not sure if i am doing it right or wrong.

One strange thing which i have noticed is that while redirecting the URL is getting changes to

```
http://localhost:9001/storefront/?errorKey=facebook.user.accessDenied
```

this is the remaining part of addErrorMessage function

```
public static void addErrorMessage(final Model model, final String messageKey)
    {
        addMessage(model, ERROR_MESSAGES_HOLDER, messageKey);
    }

protected static void addMessage(final Model model, final String messageHolder, final String messageKey)
    {
        if (model.containsAttribute(messageHolder))
        {
            final Map<String, Object> modelMap = model.asMap();
            final List<String> messageKeys = new ArrayList<String>((List<String>) modelMap.get(messageHolder));
            messageKeys.add(messageKey);
            model.addAttribute(messageHolder, messageKeys);
        }
        else
        {
            model.addAttribute(messageHolder, Collections.singletonList(messageKey));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve here. But I guess that you are trying to show the error message after validation done at controller level and then want to show the same form again but with error messages.

I am also confused with your **REDIRECT_PREFIX** variable. What is its value??
If you are using the "redirect:" as its value then it is the problem. When you redirect to other view then the error message you have attached to the model properties will not get displayed in the form. You need to just specify the view name where your form is displayed and spring will automatically show the errors there binded with your model property.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: yes you are correct `REDIRECT_PREFIX=redirect`. I was having same guess about losing value.Is there any way to retain this while using `redirect`

Comment: No you should not use redirect because it will not preserve your model and BindingResult object. When you redirect it will call the controller for the mapped request mapping as your url.

Comment: my problem is i have to send back user to same location from where he/she has come from and using simple view is not possible as per the underlying framework structure :(

Comment: Then you need to find some other way out. :-)

Comment: That is what i am trying to find out but have not got any success so far :(